# Can I create a bootable Windows 7 installation USB from within Ubuntu to boot a 2010 model iMac?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, uefi, mac

I have a 2010 model iMac on which I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 as the sole OS.

I would like to install Windows 7 as a dual boot. I have freed up some space on the HDD.

No matter what I try, I am unable to boot the iMac from either a Windows 7 USB or a Windows 7 DVD.

Is this possible at all? What do I need to do to create a bootable Windows 7 installation USB for the iMac?

**So far I have tried:**

- Using Brasero to burn the ISO image to a DVD - could not boot from this DVD
- Using UNetbootin to create a bootable USB from an ISO image (as well as modifying the boot folder on the USB to add a bootx64.efi file) - could not boot from this USB.

**Unique issues for this question:**

- Install Windows 7 and not Windows 8
- Install Windows 7 on an iMac
- Install Windows 7 in UEFI mode
- Tried the USB method mentioned in another question - iMac cannot boot from the USB

Comment: @markkirby Thanks, my question is unique and I have added reasons as to why I believe it is unique.

Comment: @markkirby I am not quite sure at this point, all I know is that I have tried the method mentioned in the question you suggested as a possible duplicate and am unable to boot the machine from that USB/DVD.

Comment: @markkirby I have an external HDD with OSX on it. I could boot the machine from that, what should I try in OSX?

Comment: OK the issue is the way a mac boots is different to a PC and you must use a specific tool to make a win 8 UEFI USB, just follow this tutorial from microsoft on your mac OSX and you will see what I mean http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/install-windows-on-mac

Comment: @markkirby Thanks very much, but I need to install Win 7, not Win 8, is your link going to work for Win 7 ? :)

Comment: Here is a better tutorial for you, that mentions working with 7 http://www.howtogeek.com/186907/how-to-install-windows-on-a-mac-with-boot-camp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booting Windows 7 in EFI mode on a Mac is tricky at best. (Note UEFI is EFI 2.x, but Macs' EFIs are all 1.x versions, so Macs technically don't have UEFIs.) There's a very long thread on MacRumors about this subject:

http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/win7-x64-booting-natively-via-efi-no-bios-emulation.696523/

To boil this thread down, *some* people have successfully installed and booted Windows 7 on *some* Macs in EFI mode. The procedures for doing so are often convoluted, and most people who attempt it fail. At least, that's my impression from the last time I reviewed it, which was over a year ago. Perhaps somebody's made a breakthrough since then.

Windows 8 is much easier to get working on Macs in EFI mode, but even it doesn't always works. I haven't been keeping track of details of which models work best in EFI mode.

Dual- or triple-booting Windows 7 on a Mac is most easily done in BIOS mode. In fact, given a Windows/Linux dual-boot on a Mac (with no OS X), by far the easiest solution is to boot both OSes in BIOS mode. If you were starting from scratch, I'd say to create an MBR partition table, boot Windows 7 in BIOS mode, install it, and then boot and install Ubuntu in BIOS mode. Maintaining an EFI-mode boot on a Mac without OS X poses some challenges because Apple has deviated from the usual EFI boot procedures, so tools like Ubuntu's `efibootmgr` may not work quite right; you really need OS X's `bless` utility to properly manage the EFI boot process. Going with a strictly BIOS-mode setup bypasses these problems.

Comment: How would I go about getting everything installed in BIOS-mode on an imac though? I don't think they support BIOS or even BIOS emulation in any way do they ?

Comment: AFAIK all x86-based Macs provide a CSM (and hence BIOS/legacy support). The earliest models require a firmware update to add this support, but I'd expect it would have been present in your 2010 model from the start. This support is typically activated when the firmware notices an MBR (or hybrid MBR) partition table or a CD/DVD with BIOS-mode boot loader. The computer can still boot in EFI mode with the CSM activated; activation of the CSM simply enables a BIOS-mode boot as an option.